# PHP cURL not working and not showing any errors

Tags: php, curl

Below is the code I have written. But its not showing anything on my screen. Am I missing anything?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set("display_errors", 1);

            $reservation_obj['source'] = "website";
            $reservation_obj['location_code'] = "test";
            $reservation_obj['start_date'] = "2010-06-01 19:00";
            $reservation_obj['end_date'] = "2010-06-04 13:50";
            $reservation_obj['action'] = "get_quotes";

            $json = json_encode($reservation_obj);

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://myserver/test.php");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/json', 'Content-length: '.strlen($json)));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,getcwd()."key/test_services.pem");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,getcwd()."key/test_services.p12");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, "P12");

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

  $output=curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

  print_r($output);
```

This is what I got on printing

```
echo "<pre>";
  var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
  echo "</pre>";
```

Below is the output I got.  And I server need the ssl certificate thats why I added the ssl things. If am wrong please help me.

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(68) "https://myserver/test.php"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.325151)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.124679)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.400445)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "204.13.111.172"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.1.75"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(36492)
}
```

After removing it I got this:

```
rray(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(68) "https://wsh.netpark.us/reservation_services/test/ws_reservations.php"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(269)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(2.50114)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.124669)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.51286)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(1.316726)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(124)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(49)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(124)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(14) "204.13.111.172"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(443)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(12) "192.168.1.75"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(36695)
}
```

Comment: print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); after exec and check what you get http code. if you not verifying SSL why you added SSL code like version etc.

Comment: Hi, I have printed the stuffs you asked. Please check it.. and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: you got ["http_code"]=>
  int(0) means not working it should be 200 for correct

Comment: try to remove curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,getcwd()."key/test_services.pem");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM"); let me know result what you get?

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,getcwd()."key/test_services.p12");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, "P12");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);

Comment: I have updated it please check it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this after you curl_exec command and before curl_close. That should print any errors.

```
if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

Comment: Warning:  curl_getinfo() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/html/api/first.php on line 47

NULL

Comment: There is no **curl_getinfo()** in my answer. Also you must run all curl_function before you call curl_close($ch). That's probably your problem.

Comment: So curl is not printing errors. You need resolve the SSL issue. The server you are talking to is probably running different ssl version than 3. 

Try another SSL version. like 2
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 2);

Comment: You can find out by using this tool what version are supported [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)